# 0 down vote SOLVED Invoice Unique Constraint Violation Magento 2.2.5 when i am generating a invoice facing this error

Tags: magento2

Just go to

> database -> `sales_invoice` -> `indexes`

just remove one rule

```
SALES_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID
```

0 down vote  SOLVED Invoice Unique Constraint Violation Magento 2.2.5 when i am generating a invoice facing this error